# What is the best website to post a job for a Windows sysadmin?

Tags: sql-server

There are a TON of sites out there to submit jobs and it could become quite expensive to submit to all of them. Any ideas on which are the most effective ones when trying to recruit Windows / MSSQL sysadmins / system engineers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hire a local headhunter/recruiting type company. Let them worry about where to post etc. All you need to pay for is the commission of finding someone. You also don't have to wade though the bull applicants. Better companies only need commission after they find someone for you.

Comment: "All you need to pay is commission", but that's 20% of first year salary! i don't think we can shoulder that kind of expense right now

Comment: As an update I ended up using Monster + VentureFizz. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duh! [Right here](http://careers.serverfault.com/jobs). Winning!

Comment: Stackoverflow Careers is still heavily (almost exclusively) for programming jobs, not system administration.

Comment: We can change that... Post some sysadmin jobs.

Answer (score 1):

How about our very own? http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Seems too obvious, but Monster.com seems to do the trick just fine.

Dice.com is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget about [Craigslist](http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites).  Lots of junk but a lot of talent browsing Craigslist as well.  My last two jobs were from Craigslist ads.  If your company does not have the time, contacting a talent agency will help as they have databases full of talent.

Comment: I agree, which is why I said a lot of junk.  However, you will be surprised how many people use it to land jobs.